# The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server

Tags: asp.net

Error Message:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.

**Client**: Windows .NET 4.0 framework
Server: UNIX

**Issue** : The webservice connection was working fine with out any issues. But sometimes it was throwing the connection was closed error. I am new to .Net frame work and i know the basis. Please guide me how to fix this issue.

**Work Around**: After recycling the application pool the issue was fixed. (Actually we are closing the old connection and re-establishing).

Any information to fix this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the KeepAlive Property to False so the connection will be closed by itself and re opened for every request. **This will avoid the issue of attempting to use a closed connection.**

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Setting KeepAlive to false can have severe performance implications.  Unless this is a low-volume situation, I wouldn't recommend it.